# Enumerating in multicols gives unwanted whitespace between lines

Tags: enumitem, multicol, examdesign

I am trying to set up a multiple answer sheet with several short answers, but when I try to use the multicol environment, it creates unwanted whitspace.

The code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\summation}[2]{\sum\limits^{#1}_{#2}}

\begin{document}
\textbf{11)} The expression $\frac{\sin{x} + \sin{y}}{\cos{x} + \cos{y}}$ is equal to
    \begin{enumerate}[(A)]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $\tan{\frac{x + y}{2}}$ % CORRECT
        \item $\tan{\frac{x - y}{2}}$
        \item $2\tan{x + y}$
        \item $2\tan{x - y}$
        \item $2\tan{2 x y}$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Any advice on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding instructions to your LaTeX code to make it compilable. I've also moved the screenshot from an external server to the body of your query. Feel free to revert.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77910078/2777074

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Thanks for pointing out the cross-posting issue.

Comment: Off-topic: There is no *environment* called `multicol`; the name of the environment is `multicols`. And, yes, it's a bit unfortunate that the `multicols` environment is provided by a *package* called `multicol`...

Comment: Unfortunately, multicols* puts everything in one column.  `\raggedbottom` doesn't work either.  Adding `\vfill\null` to the end will take up the extra space, though.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the stretchiness (TeX jargon: "glue") that's built into the low-level `itemsep` parameter. This may be done by replacing `\begin{enumerate}[(A)]` with, say, `\begin{enumerate}[(A),itemsep=1ex]`. If you want to minimize the inter-item distance, use `nosep` instead of `itemsep=1ex`.

Do note that the macros `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\tan` don't take an argument delimited by curly braces. This point may seem harmless for `\sin{x}` and `\cos{y}`, which resolve to `\sin x` and `\cos y`, respectively. However, the instructions `\tan{x + y}`, `2\tan{x - y}` and `2\tan{2 x y}` may look right at first glance, but their output is wrong. For instance, `\tan{x - y}` resolves to `\tan x - y`, i.e., `\tan` might be taken to apply only to `x`, not to `x - y`. Hence, what you *should* be writing is `\tan(x + y)`, `2\tan(x - y)`, and `2\tan(2 x y)`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
%% Note: I've stripped down the code to the bare essentials.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{11)} The expression $\frac{\sin x + \sin y}{\cos x + \cos y}$ is equal to
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[(A),itemsep=1ex]
        \item $\tan \frac{x + y}{2}$ % CORRECT
        \item $\tan \frac{x - y}{2}$
        \item $2\tan(x + y)$
        \item $2\tan(x - y)$
        \item $2\tan(2 x y)$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```